# Need to understand fomula re: excel search for a string in a table and return string if true

Tags: excel, excel-formula, find, lookup

I've adapted this solution from a couple of years ago:

```
=LOOKUP(2^15,FIND(Keywords,A2),Categories)
```

I use this for searching within a description field for keywords in a named list, in order to return a corresponding category from an adjacent named list.

However I do not understand the significance of 2^15. Can someone explain?

Also it's unclear in what order the search operates. If two keyword options were "check" and "deposit," and they were assigned to different categories, but both appeared in the same description field cell, how do I know which will be found first? Is it placement in the string, or order in the list?

Answer (score 0):

2^15 is simply an arbitrarily large number, which lookup attempts to find - when it can't find it, it takes the next lowest number.

Effectively your formula looks at Keywords, and attempts to find the value in A2. For each word that actually matches A2, it provides a non-error message. Then out of the whole list, it attempts to find that line number in categories, resulting in many errors, and a single correct value. Lookup picks the value by using 2^15. Though this seems to be a weird way of doing it; it is likely a holdover of pre-2007, as Lookup is generally used now only for backwards compatibility purposes. Also using 1 instead of 2^15 worked for a couple of simple cases that I tried when writing this up.

Comment: My guess is that pre-2007, Lookup only sorted 1-way, meaning the search value needed to be high. Now however it looks like it tries to search both ways if the other way finds an error.

Comment: The point is that 2^15 is exactly one number larger than the maximum limit of characters that can be entered into any cell. FIND() cannot return a position number this large. But in virtually all cases a much smaller value will do.

Comment: My list has 70 keywords (in various case combinations) and when I change the number in the formula to 1, it returns an error. I tried the formula using a value of 75 and that seems to return the correct category. So does that just mean the number simply needs to be larger than the set of values I'm having it search? And what of the order or priority of which keyword is matched first if more than one appears in a single cell?

Comment: In terms of priority it will take the one last in the list, because as you indicate this looks for the highest possible value and goes down (admittedly i only tried this with a list of 2 items and both worked with '1' instead of 2^15). Note also that 2^15 itself may have been originally designed at some point due to a natural excel threshold, as it is a power of 2 [ie, increasing multiples of bits].

Comment: If you want different functionality you should ask as a new question [after looking through previously asked questions]; there are a lot of ways to do something similar and you can likely find one that does what you need better.

Comment: Thanks for the responses!